# Facebook iOS SDK returns "HTTP status code: 400" when posting achievement

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to post achievements to users' Facebook graphs with the SDK 3.1.1, but I keep getting a "HTTP status code: 400" error in the log every time the achievement URL is sent.  I've registered the URL correctly and everything checks out with Facebook's little debugger tool when I paste the URL in.  Publishing permissions are also granted and the whole authentication process happens without a hitch.  I'm using a dummy user ID at the moment, but here's the code I'm working with inside the function that sends the achievement...

```
NSMutableDictionary* params =   [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                                      [achievementURLs objectAtIndex:achievement]], @"achievement",
                                     nil];
userID = 100004505160614;

[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i/achievements", userID] parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    }];
```

Any ideas where this error might be coming from?